# iPhone SDK - How to display a photo taken with the camera inside a UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, camera

This is my code so far:

```
/* class: myViewController
@interface myViewController: UIViewController
       <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
*/
- (IBAction) getPicture {
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
       picker.delegate = self;
       picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
       [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)thePicker 
                    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)imageInfo
{
    [[thePicker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
       UIImage *img = [imageInfo
                           objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    self.myImageView.image = img;
}
```

So basically I'm trying to get a photo from the iPhone camera and display it in a UIImageView. This works perfectly fine as long the class myViewController is displayed as a standalone view. If I'm putting the View inside a UINavigationController the UIImageView won't display the image after taking one with the camera. But if I choose a picture from the library everything is fine again.

So why does the UIImageView won't display a image taken with the camera inside a UINavigationController?

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch the following lines:

```
[thePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
UIImage *img = [imageInfo objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
self.myImageView.image = img;
```

to the following:

```
UIImage *img = [imageInfo objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
self.myImageView.image = img;
[thePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Perhaps the image is released because of the dismissing of the view before you retain it with

```
self.myImageView.image = img;
```

Comment: Have you tried the following after setting the image?

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you're dismissing the wrong viewcontroller. Shouldn't:

```
[thePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

read:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: I've just tried this but it doesn't make any difference. Could you explain this to me a little more? thePicker should be the current ImagePicker.

Comment: thePicker is the current ImagePicker, but I think you're supposed to send the dismissModalViewControllerAnimated call to the view controller that created the modal view controller rather than the modal view controller itself